# Network Switch with Togglable Ports

Tags: embedded-systems, computer-hardware, networking

I'm a software engineer that works on custom embedded devices. I program these devices through a typical RJ-45 ethernet cable. In most cases, I can connect my computer to these devices through a typical network switch and update multiple devices at the same time.

However, some devices are not compatible with others, and will cause issues if connected. For example:

[image: Isolated Network Design]

I cannot have traffic from Device A reach Device B, or vice versa. Typically, I only need to be connected to one at once, so my current solution is just moving an ethernet cable that is connected to my computer to Device A or Device B, but I'd like to improve that.

I'm looking to either build or buy a togglable network switch, where the system can be in one of two states: Computer to Device A (and vice versa) or Computer to Device B (and vice versa). Basically, I minimally need to toggle ports on a network switch on and off.

I haven't been able to find something like this online, so I was wondering if I can rig a switch up by splicing some network cables and toggling them in some way, but I'm worried about interference and potential byte corruption.

Any initial suggestions?

Comment: Too late now, but you should be able to rig this up with a managed ethernet switch and some scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the ethernet toggle switch on Amazon that I was looking for. This works perfectly for what I need:

https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B077NYH15H/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1

I think the term I was originally looking for was an "Ethernet Selector".